# How do I use post-css to autoprefix SCSS without compiling to CSS?

Tags: sass, gulp, jekyll, postcss

I have a static site that is generated using Jekyll.

Directory structure:

```
| _sass/
|---| subfolder/
|---|---| _component-1.scss  
|---|---| _component-2.scss  etc
| css/
|---| main.scss
| _site/
|---| css/
|---|---| main.css
```

`main.scss` imports all my SCSS components into one file, and Jekyll compiles the SCSS into the 'source' directory (where the static site is generated) - `_site`.

I want to use an autoprefixer on my SCSS components. There are Jekyll plugins that do this, however I host the site on GitHub pages, which disables plugins for security reasons. I could use the plugin locally and then just push the `_site` directory to GitHub, but I don't want to use this option.

I want to use a Gulp task to autoprefix my SCSS components, without first compiling the SCSS to CSS. I want to simply autoprefix in my Gulp build step, and let the Jekyll build process take care of the SCSS compilation.

So I've changed the `sass_dir` in the Jekyll `_config.yml` file to be `_gulped-sass` (or whatever) instead of `_sass`, and tried the following gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var source = '_sass/**/*.scss';
var destination = '_gulped-sass';

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {   
    gulp.src(source)
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});
```

..however this gives the error:

```
$ gulp autoprefixer
$ error: you tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
```

Ok, so [the docs for post-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss)  gives the useage as

```
var syntax = require('postcss-scss');
postcss(plugins).process(scss, { syntax: syntax }).then(function(result) {
    result.content // SCSS with transformations
});
```

..and the [docs for post-css](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) give the useage as:

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
var postcss    = require('gulp-postcss');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
    .pipe( postcss([ require('precss'), require('autoprefixer') ]) )
    .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('build/') );
});
```

I cannot work out from the docs how to use the postcss-scss parser in my Gulp task. I've tried many different combinations of the two examples from the docs, but none work.

So, how can I use post-css and/or post-scss in my Gulp task in order to autoprefix my SCSS *without* compiling it to CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. The post-scss **parser** (not plugin) can be assigned as the `syntax` property of an object passed as a second parameter to the `postcss` function. It starts to look really messy, but it works:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = '_sass/**/*.scss';
var destination = '_gulped-sass';

var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {
    return gulp.src(source)
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })], {
            syntax: require('postcss-scss')
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});
```

Comment: Ran into the same problem and found this helpful.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me as of March 14th, 2020. Tried copying your exact pipe and while the scss combines it does not apply any prefixes. It is hard finding information about how to prefix and polyfill scss without compiling.